# Find if int value crossed 0 fast

Tags: c#, optimization, bit-manipulation

I want to find if an int value just has crossed 0. Or if you like if two ints are of different signs.

I want this to be **most efficient** and I **dont need to check for boundaries** ie int.MinValue etc.

Please **do not use Math** class.

```
int prevx = 0;
void Calculate(int x)
{
    if(x == 0)
        return;

    prevx = x;

    // if sign(x) != sign(prevx)
    if(<your efficient code goes here>)
        OnCross();
}
```

Will be compiled as 64bit.

**EDIT:**

I just compared (x * y) < 0 and (x ^ y) < 0 and the XOR is slightly faster than multiplication on my i7. So I am waiting on Harold to answer this and nominate it.

*For 2 * 10+8 loop XOR shows 525ms and multiplication 555ms*

Comment: What do you mean, crossed? How can a single int "cross" a value?

Comment: if `(prevx ^ x) < 0` then the signbits are different. (that's an actual xor there by the way, not exponentiation)

Comment: prevx and x are the same in your code!

Comment: @harold that should be an answer.

Comment: @Mehrdad: To get to the other side of course.

Comment: @harold - please put this into the answer. i think yours is the best.

Comment: @Bobb well Anonymouse borrowed my comment, you can vote for that one

Comment: I know he did.. why dont you do that anyway? this is my question i elect the answer i want anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `(prevx ^ x) < 0` (xor, not exponentiation) then the signbits are different.
To see why, in case someone doesn't, if the sign bits are different then the xor of them will be one, so because the sign of the result is one, it is less than zero. If the sign bits are the same, the xor will be zero, and the result will be zero or more.

Compared to multiplication, there is no overflow problem and it's faster on most processors.

Comment: btw. there is no 'sign bit' in C# ;) but thanks for the answer anyway. it works ! :)

Comment: @Bobb well it's not a "separate bit" as in sign-magnitude representation, but for 2's complement (as also used in C#), the upper bit can be interpreted as a sign bit anyway.

Comment: @Bobb: Wrong.  .Net uses sign bits.

Comment: @harold. yeah you are right. I didnt think about it this way.

Answer (score 4):

For integers, you can use **XOR** and check the sign.

```
(a ^ b) < 0
```

will be true if only one of them had the sign bit set.

Comment: this answer although produces the right result is INCORRECT. sign in C# is not a 8th or 16th etc bit set. This is not C.

Comment: @Bobb actually they work exactly the same, it's just good old two's complement

Comment: Actually, it's the other way around, this is C# not C, so we know it'll always be twos-complement, while C can be implemented ones-complement (and normally would be on a ones-complement machine).

Answer (score 2):

```
if(x * prevx < 0)
```

filler text asdf

Comment: Does this could cause a overflow which changes the result when the numbers are too large?

Comment: You can cast it to long to extend the value space.

Comment: OP states that he doesn't care about boundary check. Still I like harold/Anonymouse solution better.

Comment: Slower than xor, and doesn't work at all without inserting widening casts.

Answer (score 1):

multiply the numbers and check if the product is > or < 0